# How to sort a list of nodes by a given array in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML which is a list of elements:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="apple-0">first-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-1">second-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-2">third-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-3">forth-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-4">fifth-apple</div>
</div>
```

I've gotten an array, for example, which is `[3,4,0,2,1]` I need to sort the list in to this order.By this I mean that the third element `<div class="apple-3">third-apple</div>` should be the first. The second element should be the `forth-apple`.

How can I change it in an efficient way? This is the expected output:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="apple-3">forth-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-4">fifth-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-0">first-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-2">third-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-1">second-apple</div>
</div>
```

jQuery can be used.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry. But there is no sorting logic but only an given array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by looping through the array and appending each `div` by it's matched index. Try this:

```
var $divs = $('.container > div').detach();
[3, 4, 0, 2, 1].forEach(function(value) {
    $divs.eq(value).appendTo('.container');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/s7b8p5h5/)

Note that if you need to support older browsers (< IE9) then you would need to replace `forEach()` with a standard `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate the `indexes` array and keep pushing the child at nth-index

```
var output = [];
var indexes = [3,4,0,2,1];
indexes.forEach(function(value, index){
  output.push($(".container div").eq(indexes[index])[0].outerHTML);
});
console.log(output);
$(".container").html(output.join(""));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ruayotq6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
$("#sort").on("click", function() {
  var data = [3, 4, 0, 2, 1];
  var result = "";

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    result += $(".container").find(".apple-" + item)[0].outerHTML;
  });

  $(".container").html(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="apple-0">first-apple</div>
  <div class="apple-1">second-apple</div>
  <div class="apple-2">third-apple</div>
  <div class="apple-3">forth-apple</div>
  <div class="apple-4">fifth-apple</div>
</div>

<button id="sort">Sort</button>
```

Comment: You are so clever! Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

UPDATE:

```
var arr = [3,4,0,2,1];
var nodes = [];
arr.forEach(funtion(value){
    var node = $('.container .apple-'+value)[0];
    nodes.push(node);
            });
$('.container').html(nodes);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/nodipotipe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have added the pre-ordered example : )

Answer (score 1):

Other answers with `eq` are good, but if you want to sort again with a different array, or the array is unsorted initially, then they would fail. Also you asked for an efficient method, using native loops instead of jquery's each gives performance benefits. So my answer to this is

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var inputEls = $('#awesomeContainer').find('>').get(),
       $output = $('#awesomeOutput'),
       order = [3,4,0,2,1],
       output = [],
       myValue,
       newIndex,
       i,
       length = inputEls.length;
  
   for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
     myValue = Number((inputEls[i].className || "").replace("apple-", ""));
     if (myValue >= 0) {
       myValue = order.indexOf(myValue);
       myValue > -1 && (output[myValue] = inputEls[i].outerHTML);       
     }
   }
   
   $output.append(output.join(''));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Input: </b>
<div id="awesomeContainer" class="container">
    <div class="apple-0">first-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-1">second-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-2">third-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-3">forth-apple</div>
    <div class="apple-4">fifth-apple</div>
</div>
<br/>
<b>Sorted: </b>
<div id="awesomeOutput" class="container">
</div>
```